# Lambda: Callable variable initiated with a Runnable instance

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Just found a strange and interesting Lambda behavior.

Let's have the following class:

```
private class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // something to process
    }
}
```

The following statement is compiling and running:

```
Callable task = Task::new;
```

Could somebody explain why this is possible ?

**EDIT**:

Based on answers below, check the following statements:

1.

`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 executor.submit(Task::new);`

2.

`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 executor.submit(new Task());`

On the first glance, seems the same, but actually does a totally different thing.

What happens here is exactly the above situation.

The reason is that `ExecutorService` has two methods:

`submit(Runnable);
 submit(Callable);`

So, using the code from 1. the executor will process the following on it's internal thread:

`new Task()`

The version from 2. will actually call the `submit(Runnable)` method and the code from `Task.run` will be executed.

Conclusion: just be careful with Lambdas :)

Comment: it is called [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: It becomes much clearer when not using *raw types*: `Callable<Runnable> task = Task::new;` or `Callable<Task> task = Task::new;`

Comment: Holger, I think in this case doesn't matter. The end result is the same.

Comment: *Note*: submit the `Task::new` is not the same as `new Task()`. `new Task()` will execute the created task, another one is to create a task.

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik Of course it does matter. If you were using generics, it would be crystal-clear that `Task::new` is a method reference that creates a `Callable<Runnable>` whose task is to create and return a new `Runnable`.  It's true: you need to be careful with lambdas, but before that, you need to learn how to use them correctly, i.e. to express what your code needs to do.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, indeed, I agree, but I was thinking more on the example with `ExecutorService`, where you don't need to specify any generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Callable is *not* initialized with a `Runnable` instance, it is initialized with a method reference to the `Task` constructor that will *produce* a `Runnable` when executed.

In other words, if you execute that `Callable`, it will return a new `Task` object that has *not* yet been run. That `Task` implements `Runnable` is actually completely irrelevant here.

This would be clearer if you didn't use the raw type. `Task::new` can be assigned to `Callable<Task>` because it is something that takes no parameters and returns a Task.

Answer (score 2):

To implement the `Callable<V>` interface one must implement a method with the signature `V call()`.

Therefore, you can implement this interface with method references of any methods that take nothing and return some reference type, which includes constructor method references such as `Task::new`.

In fact, any class having a parameter-less constructor can be used this way:

```
Callable<SomeClass> callable = SomeClass::new;
```

Comment: I added a real scenario with this case in the question, check it out. I think that adding a generic type when declaring Callable doesn't change anything.

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik Since you already accepted an answer, I'm assuming you got the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, the answer was Lambda's "method reference" feature.